# Python PIL module not changing pixel colour

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i'm writing a piece of code which colours different counties in England based on a certain number, everytime i run my code it outputs "pixel coloured" which shows it has run the `pixels[width, height] = (151, 151, 151, 255)` but the output is the exact same image. Thanks for your time :)

Code below:

```
 img = Image.open(f'subdir/image/defaultColours.png')
        image = img.convert('RGB')
        pixels = img.load()
        width, height = img.size
        for width in range(width):
            for height in range(height):
                r, g, b = pixels[width, height]
                rgbValue = str(r)+"."+ str(g)+"."+ str(b)
                if rgbValue in highDefaults:
                    pixels[width, height] = (151, 151, 151, 255)
                    print("pixel coloured")
                elif rgbValue in midDefaults:
                    pixels[width, height] = (91, 91, 91, 255)
                    print("pixel coloured")
                elif rgbValue in lowDefaults:
                    pixels[width, height] = (0, 0, 0, 255)
                    print("pixel coloured")
                else:
                    pass
        image.save(f"subdir/image/final.jpg")
        print("saved")
```

my `highDefaults` List looks a bit like this: `highDefaults = [255.255.255, 23.23.23]` and i've made sure it is in the same layout as rgbValue

**What i've tried:**

- tried with and without an extra 255 value for alpha in `pixels[width, height] = (151, 151, 151, 255)`
- Changed image file type from png to jpg (same result so kept it as png)
  Can't remember what else

[Picture i need to colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubbUV.png)

Comment: I suspect that the second call to `img.load()` is reloading the file from disk, thus wiping out all the changes you just made.  Perhaps more fundamentally - you're modifying `img`, but saving `image`.

Comment: @jasonharper i removed the second img.load and saved it as img, but now my image has kind of half coloured, it looks like a diagonal line through my image with one side coloured and the other not

Comment: That's probably due to the `for height in range(height)` line - on each subsequent iteration of the `width` loop, `height` is only going up to 1 less than the previous `height`, rather than the actual height of the image.  You need to use distinct names for the sizes and the loop variables.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your help! it's fully working after making the changes you recommended.